# indexing on float values in coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
points = [[6033.02, -24791.2], [7008.29, -24257.0], [7128.66, -23434.0], [7235.19, -22899.3], [6590.0, -22308.7]]
```

and

```
centre = [37621.265, -32837.66499999999]
```

I want to translate the values of points with this function

```
def translate(center, points):
    new_points_x = []
    new_points_y = []
    new_points = []
    for i in points:
        # print(str(i[0]))
        new_points_x.append(i[0]-center[0]) 
    
    for i in points:
        new_points_y.append(i[1]-center[1])

    for i in range(0,len(new_points_x)):
        new_points.append([new_points_x[i], new_points_y[i]])

    return new_points
```

it gives me error

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried many things for float indexing but failed.

Comment: What's your question? Please read [ask]. If you're looking for debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). When I tried `translate(centre, points)`, I didn't get that error. Maybe you're passing in something wrong, like maybe you got the arguments backwards?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing the `center` and `points` in the wrong order to the function. Doing that causes the points to be a list instead of list of lists and `i` would be a float instead of list.

Try with -

```
points = [[6033.02, -24791.2], [7008.29, -24257.0], [7128.66, -23434.0], [7235.19, -22899.3], [6590.0, -22308.7]]
centre = [37621.265, -32837.66499999999]

def translate(center, points):
    new_points_x = []
    new_points_y = []
    new_points = []
    for i in points:
        new_points_x.append(i[0]-center[0]) 
    
    for i in points:
        new_points_y.append(i[1]-center[1])

    for i in range(0,len(new_points_x)):
        new_points.append([new_points_x[i], new_points_y[i]])

    return new_points

print(translate(centre, points))
```

**Output:**

```
[[-31588.245, 8046.464999999993], [-30612.975, 8580.664999999994], [-30492.605, 9403.664999999994], [-30386.075, 9938.364999999994], [-31031.265, 10528.964999999993]]
```